# Lying to customer service

Tags: sheker-false

The Torah says that you should stay away from sheker.

If you ordered something online through a friend's account (with his permission) but used your own credit card, when calling customer service regarding the ordered item (again with his permission), can you pretend to be your friend by saying his name when they ask?

Otherwise they probably won't be willing to speak with you.

Comment: Why this bother you when you used his account and pretended to be him?

Comment: Yes it would be as much sheker to use his account without impersonating him in-person

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that pretending to be your friend is lying (sheker). You agree with what it says in ["Halacha for Today .com](http://halachafortodaycom.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/archives-hilchos-midvar-sheker-tirchak.html)

> Lying is one of the most disgraceful sins. So much so that the Torah
>   doesn’t simply say not to do it, rather the Posuk (Shmos 23:7) tells
>   us to **distance ourselves from untruth**, Midvar Sheker Tirchak, an
>   admonition not found by any other prohibition in the Torah.

So, if your friend was good enough to allow you to use his account, why not ask him to make the call as well?

Comment: You just repeated the first line of the question...

Comment: @AniYodeya I upvoted your comment! I will add to the answer that pretending to be your friend seems to me to be sheker.

Comment: "The Torah (Shmos 23:7) ... tells us to distance ourselves from untruth, Midvar Sheker Tirchak, an admonition not found by any other prohibition in the Torah." What about "VeEl Ishah BeNidath Tumathah Lo Thikrav" (Ref.to Niddah)? I know it's not your quote. I'm just pointing it out.

Comment: @SethJ "Distance" and "don't get close" are not necessarily the same. (but +1 on your comment anyway)

Comment: Isn't using his account already pretending to be him??

Comment: @doubleaa not necessarily - using his account to purchase something for yourself makes you a sheliach.

Comment: Citing a more compelling primary source will make your answer stronger. It is permitted to lie to prevent someone from taking what is rightfully yours מותר להעביר על המכס במקום שאין דינא דמלכותא